# iptables: IP forwarding restricted to pings. Why?

Tags: iptables, opensuse, ip-forwarding

After reinstalling OpenSuSE Leap 15.5 on a SOHO server, which acts AS a Firewall, the machines on the internal network (169.254.164.0/24) can't reach any hosts on the internet save for pings. But no meaningful Traffic, not even DNS, works.

One of the server's NICs (eth0) hangs on a DSL Router, whereas eth1 is connected to the switch of the internal network. Ipv4 forwarding is switched on: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Here' s the network config of the server:

```bash
valen:~ # ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN grou
p default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP gr
oup default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:dd:a9:d4:1e:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet 192.168.178.41/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP gr
oup default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:dd:a9:d4:1e:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 169.254.164.1/24 brd 169.254.164.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

valen:~ # ip route show
default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp
169.254.164.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.164.1
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.41

valen:~ # iptables -t nat -nv -L >> netconfig.txt
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 41 packets, 2456 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 909 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination
   12 909 MASQUERADE all -- * eth0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0
.0.0/0
    0 0 LOG all -- * eth0 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.
0.0/0 LOG flags 0 level 7 prefix "MASQUERADE: "

valen:~ # iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 496 packets, 40562 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 36 packets, 2276 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination
    0 0 LOG all -- eth0 any anywhere anyw
here LOG level debug prefix "FORWARD: "
   36 2276 LOG all -- eth1 any anywhere anyw
here LOG level debug prefix "FORWARD: "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 307 packets, 43133 bytes)
 pkts bytes target prot opt in out source dest
ination

valen:~ # dmesg | grep MASQUERADE | tail -25
[ 5040.328157] x_tables: ip_tables: MASQUERADE target: used from hooks P
REROUTING, but only usable from POSTROUTING

valen:~ # iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [271:12228]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:180]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [188:13601]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
[188:13601] -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "MASQUERADE: " --log-le
vel 7
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1055426:82517132]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1055140:82499096]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [286:18036]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [197144:2649496105]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [197178:2649498961]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1055426:82517132]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [197145:2649496485]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [1054928:82491464]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [34:2856]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [197146:2649496917]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [129181:24309644]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [96:5856]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [95693:121943383]
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD: " --log-level 7
[96:5856] -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD: " --log-level
 7
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 30 22:21:59 2023
```

And this ist how one of the clients is set up:

```bash
╭─jacek@epica ~
╰─➤ ip addr show
                                  2 ↵
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN grou
p default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast sta
te UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:c6:e9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0
    inet 169.254.164.5/24 brd 169.254.164.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
╭─jacek@epica ~
╰─➤ ip route show
default via 169.254.164.1 dev eth0
169.254.164.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.164.5
```

I can ping any external host (say, 8.8.8.8) from the client, but anything beyond is not working, not even DNS queries. The syslog on the server then displays outgoing traffic, but nothing ingoing:

```bash
[12810.381486] FORWARD: IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=14:dd:a9:d4:1e:71:b4:2e:99:
c6:e9:9f:08:00 SRC=169.254.164.5 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 T
TL=63 ID=47287 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=51059 DPT=53 LEN=37
[12810.381551] FORWARD: IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=14:dd:a9:d4:1e:71:b4:2e:99:
c6:e9:9f:08:00 SRC=169.254.164.5 DST=8.8.4.4 LEN=57 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 T
TL=63 ID=31354 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=42060 DPT=53 LEN=37
```

What's wrong here?

**UPDATE:** The `tcpdump` tool shows normal traffic when pinging `8.8.8.8`, but when trying to give a hostname like `www.nwzonline.de` as a target, I can't see any response from the DNS server:

```bash
valen:~ # tcpdump -v -ni eth1 'ip host 8.8.8.8' and icmp
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length
 262144 bytes
22:14:57.356849 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63021, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to ICMP (1), length 84)
    169.254.164.5 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1, length 64
22:14:57.370168 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto
 ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 169.254.164.5: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1, length 64
22:14:58.358802 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63032, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to ICMP (1), length 84)
    169.254.164.5 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 2, length 64
22:14:58.372195 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto
 ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 169.254.164.5: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 2, length 64
22:14:59.360447 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63211, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to ICMP (1), length 84)
    169.254.164.5 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 3, length 64
22:14:59.373668 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto
 ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 169.254.164.5: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 3, length 64
22:15:00.362346 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63238, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to ICMP (1), length 84)
    169.254.164.5 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4, length 64
22:15:00.375229 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto
 ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 169.254.164.5: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4, length 64
22:15:01.364456 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63472, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to ICMP (1), length 84)
    169.254.164.5 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 5, length 64
22:15:01.377348 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto
 ICMP (1), length 84)
    8.8.8.8 > 169.254.164.5: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 5, length 64
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

valen:~ # tcpdump -v -ni eth1 'ip host 8.8.8.8'
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length
 262144 bytes
22:17:33.070802 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10602, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.33703 > 8.8.8.8.53: 8530+ A? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
22:17:33.070803 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10603, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.33703 > 8.8.8.8.53: 63569+ AAAA? www.nwzonline.de. (34
)
22:17:33.071009 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61652, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.34979 > 8.8.8.8.53: 8530+ A? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
22:17:33.071010 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61653, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.34979 > 8.8.8.8.53: 63569+ AAAA? www.nwzonline.de. (34
)
22:17:38.076881 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18807, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.42033 > 8.8.8.8.53: 14966+ A? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
22:17:38.076881 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18808, offset 0, flags [DF], pro
to UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.42033 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6003+ AAAA? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
22:17:38.077121 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1207, offset 0, flags [DF], prot
o UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.40930 > 8.8.8.8.53: 14966+ A? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
22:17:38.077122 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1208, offset 0, flags [DF], prot
o UDP (17), length 62)
    169.254.164.5.40930 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6003+ AAAA? www.nwzonline.de. (34)
^C
8 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Setting `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 1` does not help, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use for this kind of things, the shorewall package, which makes very easy to create rules.

The I create the interfaces, policy, masq, rules files, and modify the shorewall.conf to have ip_forward=1. And everything works like a charm, with the same network configuration you provided.

Give it a try.
Best regards,

HeCSa.

Edit:

Hi again!

Let me show you an example, based on a configuration I have.

I have two network interfaces, one facinf the Internet, other the internal network. ip a outputs something like this: 


`root@bastion:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:32:55:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global ens3
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe32:550c/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:93:6e:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.100.119.1/24 brd 10.100.119.255 scope global ens9
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe93:6e49/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`


ens3 faces the internet, ens9 the internal network.

Installed the shorewall package. All configuration files are in  `/etc/shorewall` 
policy: 

`fw      all     ACCEPT  info
wan     all     DROP    info
lan     all     ACCEPT  info`


zones: 

`fw      firewall
wan     ipv4
lan     ipv4`


shorewall.conf (only changed the following line): 

`IP_FORWARDING=Yes`


interfaces: 

`wan     ens3
lan     ens9`


masq: 

`ens3:0.0.0.0/0  10.100.119.0/0`

rules: 

`ACCEPT  wan     fw      tcp     22      -       -       # External SSH if needed
ACCEPT  lan     wan     icmp    8       -       -       # ping
ACCEPT  lan     fw     icmp    8       -       -       # ping
ACCEPT  lan     wan     udp     53      -       -       # dns queries
ACCEPT  lan     wan     tcp     80      -       -       # http
ACCEPT  lan     wan     tcp     443      -       -       # https`


Then enabled and started shorewall: 

`systemctl enable shorewall
systemctl start shorewall`


And after rebooting, everything worked just fine. 
Hope it helps!
Best regards,
HeCSa.

Comment: Im gonna give it a try and tell you about the results.

Comment: Hi again!
Let me show you an example, based on a configuration I have.

Comment: Check my edit, there you have a fully funtional example ;-)

Comment: Aaah, this looks much simpler than the iptables config.

Comment: Give it a try. If it works for you, don't forget to mark mine as a correct answer ;-)

Comment: For an NFS server running on the same machine as Shorewall, I'd have to add the following rule, I suppose: `ACCEPT          lan             $FW             tcp             2049`

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps:

- Check the correctness of routing with command `ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 169.254.164.1 iif eth0` on the gateway. It should show you some valid route via eth0 interface.
- Please use the `iptables-save -c` and paste it into the question. It really will help to understand your rule set.
- At very strange issue run the tcpdump. Try `tcpdump -ni eth1 'ip host 8.8.8.8' and icmp` - I think it will show you something interesting.
- After changes of nat rules restart ping command on client. It relates with the conntrack and the nat table passing specifics.

Comment: `valen:~ # ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 169.254.164.1 iif eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`

Comment: Added the info you requested in my original question.